# on mouse enter misbehaving in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have this on-mouse-enter trigger code (JavaScript to listen for mouse enters and CSS for transitions) and lately, it's been acting funny in Chrome; tested on v 44.0.2403.157m without any error in the console. By acting funny, I mean that fade in-out effect sometimes is skipping.

```js
var shown = true;
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var child = document.querySelector('.child');

parent.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  child.style.opacity = shown ? 0 : 1;
  shown = !shown;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

The code should work like we have in [this](http://goo.gl/2kM9j) example. 
I would greatly appreciate to have your code alternatives and thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and there are multiple reports about this issue like [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451756) or [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/w4YlFvEMQNw).Your code works as expected for me in both Firefox(38.0.5) and Edge(20.10240.16384.0).I assume this problem is caused by Chrome considering your code is written well.

Comment: Thank you Jay for your effort and answer, It will be interesting to know if there is any code alternative achieving the same effect like we have in the above site example fully functional in IE, Firefox but also in Chrome.Kind regards,

Comment: I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Thanks, As we can see there [link](http://goo.gl/2kM9j), on mouseenter we have a variable opacity transition + fade in-out effect. It could be pure css (?!)

Comment: I've tried everything I'm capable of in Javascript: from dynamically generating images through delays and intervals to reseting innerHTML content of containers but it does not seem to work.Also I've taken a look into your link and found that opacity change of element is handled by JQuery, not pure css.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Anyway, it looks like it's not affected by crossbrowsing as long as it works flawless in main browsers like Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Comment: can you reproduce that code? (JQuery will be fine too)